# unable to capture the response when using a callback with the ListenableFuture returned by send methods of KakfaTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, google-cloud-storage, spring-cloud, spring-kafka

I am using KafkaTemplate that provides asynchronous send methods returning a Future and then register a callback with the listener to receive the result of the send asynchronously, but onFailure I need to capture the message and store it in a GCS bucket but due to some unknown reason, I'm unable to do so. Below is the code snippet -:

```
public void send(String message) {

ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(Topic, message);
future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
    LOG.info("message received is : " + result.toString());
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
      String dateFolder = dateFormat.format(new Date());
      
      Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
      String failureFolder = failureDirectory + "/testing" + "/" + dateFolder;
      String bucket = failureFolder.split("/")[2];
      BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucket, failureFolder.split(bucket + "/")[1]);
      BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
      Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, message.getBytes());
      
      LOG.info("Writing to failure folder successful...");
  }
});
```

}

Comment: `>I'm unable to do so.` What do you mean? Since the callback is in the scope of the `send()` method, you have access to the `message` object - otherwise your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Please provide more details like what errors you are getting and what debugging steps you have taken. If you think that the issue is related to Google Cloud Storage and not related to code you can create a Public Issue for Cloud Storage under "Storage and Databases". Please select Private component if you need to share any project specific information so that it is not visible to public and one of the GCP support agent will assist you.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list